# Calculate height of element when clicking on another - Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to do the following: when clicking on one element, I open another one. I need to calculate the height of that element I just opened.

I don't know how to do it because I have no event on the element I am opening, I will provide a small example code just so you get the idea what I want to do.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">
    <div (click)="openRight = !openRight" class="click-element"></div>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="openRight" class="right">

  </div>
</div>
```

The goal is to dynamically set the height of left element based on the height of right element. Right element will have position absolute, that is the reason I need to get the height.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `DOM` element in angular using `#`. Then when you get the click event you can access the right element and get it's height.

---

**HTML**

```
<div #rightElement class="right">
</div>
```

---

**TS**

```
import { ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('rightElement') rightElement: ElementRef;


// get the height
this.rightElement.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
```

---

**@EDIT**

Why you have an undefined child is because you are using `*ngIf` condition. I think you are doing something like :

```
clickEventFunction($event) {
  ...

  this.openRight = true;

  ...

  // Use of the #rightElement
  this.rightElement.nativeElement.offsetHeight 

  ...  
}
```

The problem is that angular will only see that you modified `openRight` after the execution of `clickEventFunction`, so `#rightElement` do not exist and ... `UNDEFINED`!

What you can do, is to say to angular that you did a change, so it will create the right element and then you could use of `#rightElement`.

**Example :**

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from 'angular2/core';

constructor(protected chRef: ChangeDetectorRef){
  ...
}

clickEventFunction($event) {
  ...

  this.openRight = true;

  // Tell angular to look at openRight
  this.chRef.detectChanges();

  ...

  // Use of the #rightElement
  this.rightElement.nativeElement.offsetHeight 

  ...  
}
```

Comment: Ah yeah, ViewChild.. However, now the problem is the following, the #rightElement doesn't exist in DOM at first, it shows on click, so I get an error that #rightElement is undefined. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

you can try below code :

```
<div #mainScreen></div>
```

in **component** file

```
 import { ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

export class viewApp{

  @ViewChild('mainScreen') elementView: ElementRef;
  viewHeight: number;

clickMe(){
        this.viewHeight = this.elementView.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
          }
}
```

or

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="clickMe($event.currentTarget)"></div>

clickMe(dom){
  let viewHeight=dom.clientHeight;
}
```

Comment: Check out my comment bellow as well, this works great, but my rightElement doesn't exist at start so i get an error that it is undefined